# Connection refused when calling quit on driver

Tags: appium

Why do I get this errror sometimes

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

when I call `quit` on the Appium driver?

Answer (score 2):

For some reason your appium session is finished before `quit` is called. It can be related to appium service exception, or session timeout - check service logs and you will understand it.
It makes sense to check session status before calling `quit` to avoid errors.